# Ubuntu - mandatory restart/reboot time

Tags: reboot, restart, ssl, automatic

My Ubuntu server needs a reboot and I checked which package is asking for restart. Later, I found that libssl package needs a system reboot.

But, I don't want to restart/reboot my machine now. Is there a possible way to find out when my OS will get restarted automatically?

Generally, for how many days will it go without automatic restart/reboot of the OS?

Comment: I've never ever seen Ubuntu restart automatically.

Comment: Ok. Will packages force the OS to restart?

Comment: As said above, I've never seen it happen, but theoretically, it is not impossible. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done some research I believe that Ubuntu will not restart automatically unless a chronjob is created telling it to [Here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1941781) is how to create such a chronjob otherwise I would just do a manual restart. If you don't reboot a server, it can go on for many many months.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. Go to the machine and take the network connection down and up.
See if the libssl package still needs a system reboot?

Comment: Yes, it needs a reboot as there are some dependent packages on it.

Comment: That does not really answer the OPs question